# A particular usage of StrongBox

Tags: roslyn

I am looking at the [Roslyn September 2012 CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) with Reflector, and I noticed the following depth-first traversal of the syntax tree:

```cs
private IEnumerable<CommonSyntaxNode> DescendantNodesOnly(TextSpan span,
    Func<CommonSyntaxNode, bool> descendIntoChildren, bool includeSelf)
{
    if (includeSelf && IsInSpan(span, FullSpan))
    {
        yield return this;
    }

    if ((descendIntoChildren != null) && !descendIntoChildren(this))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var queue = new Queue<StrongBox<IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>>>();
    var stack = new Stack<StrongBox<IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>>>();
    stack.Push(new StrongBox<IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>>(ChildNodes().GetEnumerator()));
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var enumerator = stack.Peek();
        StrongBox<IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>> childEnumerator;
        if (enumerator.Value.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Value.Current;
            if (IsInSpan(span, current.FullSpan))
            {
                yield return current;

                if ((descendIntoChildren == null) || descendIntoChildren(current))
                {
                    childEnumerator = queue.Count == 0
                        ? new StrongBox<IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>>()
                        : queue.Dequeue();
                    childEnumerator.Value = current.ChildNodes().GetEnumerator();
                    stack.Push(childEnumerator);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            childEnumerator = stack.Pop();
            childEnumerator.Value = null;
            queue.Enqueue(childEnumerator);
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing that the queue is to ease the runtime from allocating and deallocating so many instances of `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>`.

However, I am not sure why `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>` is wrapped in `StrongBox<>`. What sort of performance and safety trade-offs are involved in wrapping `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>`, which is usually a value type, inside the reference type `StrongBox<>`?

Answer (score 3):

`CommonSyntaxNode` is an abstact class which contains alot of value types and can be inherited into a big object.

`IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>` contains only a reference to a `CommonSyntaxNode` so it seems like the size of the `CommonSyntaxNode` won't affect the `Enumerator` size since it's only a reference, *but*:

since *`IEnumerator<T>`*'s method *`MoveNext()`* uses `yield return;` each iteration in the `Enumerator` will cause the method to save it's state untill the next iteration.

since the whole method state is heavy enough and it might contain `CommonSyntaxNode`'s properties in order to do the *`MoveNext()`* logic, than the whole `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>` might be pretty heavy on memory.

using *`StrongBox<>`* causes the `Queue` or `Stack` hold only a small reference object (the `StrongBox<>` instead of the potentially heavy on memory `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>` - therefore - the GC is cleaning the *`Queue` or `Stack`*'s contained `IEnumerator<CommonSyntaxNode>` from the memory potentially faster - ***reducing the application total memory consumption.***

note that `CommonSyntaxNode`'s enumerator is a struct which working with it directly means deeply copying the whole struct, it's a small struct so it's not really heavy but still...

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of the `StrongBox<T>` is once an item is dequeued, the StrongBox clears out it's  internal content - so the GC can then collect the instance of T being held by StrongBox and the `Queue<T>` ends up holding just an instance of StrongBox (instead of an instance of T).

Answer (score 0):

The use of IEnumerator was a mistake.  The code should have been using ChildSyntaxList.Enumerator, which is a struct.  The use of StrongBox is for perf, to keep from needing to push & pop the enumerators from the end of the stack when they change.

Comment: I do not see how using StrongBox makes a difference, since you still need to push and pop each instance of StrongBox from the end of the stack when it changes.